# Unable to find "dt~mocha" ("npm") in the registry

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, typescript, mocha.js, typescript-typings

I am trying to setup mocha and chai in my current typescript project.

I am going through below page to implement the same:-

https://journal.artfuldev.com/write-tests-for-typescript-projects-with-mocha-and-chai-in-typescript-86e053bdb2b6

```
$ typings install dt~mocha --global --save
```

I am getting error while running above command in Ubuntu:-

---

```
typings ERR! message Unable to find "dt~mocha" ("npm") in the registry. Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you want to contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/dt~mocha/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200

typings ERR! cwd /home/abhishek/Desktop/TypeScript/automation/jasmine
typings ERR! system Linux 3.19.0-47-generic
typings ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/typings" "install" "dt~mocha" "--global" "--save"
typings ERR! node -v v7.7.3
typings ERR! typings -v 0.8.1

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

---

I tried searching the internet. Also, I tried a couple of things but it failed.

Any ideas on this on how can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the page and instead of running below commands:-

```js
$ typings install dt~mocha --global --save
$ typings install npm~chai --save
```

I see there is a command on the page you have shared which you can use:-

There is now another method to add type definitions, from TypeScript 2.0, so we can also use that instead of the typings method mentioned above. This method does not depend upon the typings npm package or module. To make use of this, type the following commands:

```js
$ npm install @types/chai @types/mocha --save-dev
```

I followed the rest of the steps and it worked !!!

I know this may not be the ultimate solution but should do.